# Using modualr arithmetic for vector indices in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, modular-arithmetic

I have a vector n values and i want to split it into groups n groups of 3 adjacent values if it is considered to have a ring topology.

what i am trying to do is this:

```
vector = [some values];
groups = {};

for i = 1:size(vector)(2)
    groups{i} = [vector(mod(i-1, size(vector)(2));
                 vector(i);
                 vector(mod(i+1, size(vector)(2))];
endfor
```

so if n = 10 and i = 1, groups should be [vector(10); vector(1); vector(2)]

it would be pretty straightforward in most programming languages to just use the mod operator, but i am having trouble working out how to do this using matlab as it doesnt use 0 as the initial index of a vector, so if i = 1, then mod(i-1) = 0 which is an illegal index value. Also i = n would be a problem as mod(n, n) = 0.

i have worked out a pretty hack-ish solution in:

```
vector = [some values];
groups = {};

for i = 1:size(vector)(2)
    if i == 1
        groups{i} = [vector(size(vector)(2));
                     vector(1);
                     vector(2)];
    elseif i == size(vector)(2)
        groups{i} = [vector(size(vector)(2)-1);
                     vector(size(vector)(2);
                     vector(1)];
    else
        groups{i} = [vector(i-1);
                     vector(i);
                     vector(i+1)];
    endif
endfor
```

but it is pretty inelegant and i feel like there should be a better way to do it..

is there some operator that allows you to perform modular arithmetic over vector indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the 1-based indexing method of matlab can be quite irritating sometimes...
You can simply add 1 to your 0-based indices, though

```
n = numel(vector);
for ii = 1:n
    idx0 = mod( ii + [-2, 1, 0], n ); % 0-based indices
    group{ii} = vector( idx0 + 1 );
end
```

Now, good Matlab practices are about [vectorization](/questions/tagged/vectorization), here's one way to vectorize this for-loop

```
idx0 = mod( bsxfun( @plus, 1:n, [-2;1;0] ), n ); % all indices at once
group = mat2cell( vector( idx0+1 ).', ones(n,1), 3 );
```

You can lookup [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) in mathworks web site for more information. You can also read about [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun) here at SO for more examples and information.

---

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: Smart solution with that `bsxfun`!

Comment: thanks a lot for that, it works for what i need, and i'm pretty sure that i understand what is going on, i havent had a lot of experience with matlab up until now so it looks like i have a lot to learn. If you aren't too busy, can you give a brief description of what is happening in that vectorisation? If not i can do some reading myself. Thanks a lot for your help at any rate.

Comment: actually, now that i look closely, this solution doesnt quite give me what i am after; groups{1} of the solution you provided gives {vector(1); vector(2); vector(3)} whereas it should give {vector(n); vector(1); vector(2)}. is achieving that as simple as changing the [-1 0 1] part to [-2 1 0]?

Comment: changed [-1 0 1] to [-2 -1 0] and it worked fine, thanks again

Comment: @guskenny83 I suppose it is indeed as easy as the change you proposed.